# Two different random.choices from a list (python)

Tags: python, random

Complete python noob here but I am slowly wrapping my head around it.
I am making a 1v1 Halo 3 tournament style program that randomly matches players and picks the map, gametype etc...

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to randomly recall two *different* strings from a list.

```
playerList = ["Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", "Player 4"]
```

So say this was the list of players, how would I print:

> Player 1 vs Player 3

I have tried a few different things to no avail. I do have a little bit of an understanding of the `random` library but I can't figure out exactly how to do this

ie print random.choice(playerList) + " vs " + random.choice(playerList) eventually will have the same players versing each other when you've run it enough times...

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `random.sample`. You want to pick 2 out of the list:

```
import random

playerList = ["Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", "Player 4"]
player1, player2 = random.sample(playerList, 2)
print '{} vs. {}'.format(player1, player2)
```